# Error: cannot find symbol—Can't access another class's public field

Tags: java, scope

Ok so here is my code:

```
class ConnectionTest implements Connection {
    Random randomGenerator;
    public String id;

    public ConnectionTest() {
        randomGenerator = new Random();
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    public boolean testConnection() {
        if (randomGenerator.nextInt(10)<3) //randomly make some false.
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

class ConnectionFactoryTest implements ConnectionFactory {

    public Connection newConnection() {

        Connection c = new ConnectionTest();
        if (c == null)
            throw new ConnectionException("New connection failed.");
        System.out.println("New connection: " + c.id);
        return new ConnectionTest();
    }
}
```

And the compiler complains that `c` doesn't have `id`. I have declared `id` as public, so shouldn't it be accessible by other classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler checks at **compile time** the type of `c`'s reference : and since it's a `Connection` reference (the `Connection` class has no `id` attribute), **compilation fails**.

This code should work:

```
ConnectionTest c = new ConnectionTest();
```

One workaround for `Connection c = new ConnectionTest();` to work is to define the `id` member variable in the **Connection** class instead.

Comment: Even though it's an instance of ConnectionTest? Oh I see, so the type is declared first, and the constructor's fields are kind of ignored?

Comment: They're not "ignored", it's just the way JVM works. It only sees the reference (`Connection`) type attributes, not the `ConnectionTest`'s.

Comment: You would need to cast `c` to `ConnectionTest` (which is usually not a good idea) to access `id` field

Comment: @Mirror318 The type of the *object* is allowed to be different from the type of the *variable*. A variable of type `Connection` could hold a reference to any object that implements `Connection`, and not all of those will have an `id` field.